# Automatically send email on torrent completion

Tags: sendemail

I have set up my pi to be a media server and a seed box. I have the transmission daemon running in the background. I am able to successfully access the transmission web gui from my laptop. Now I am trying to make the daemon send an email automatically on torrent completion. Here is the script I wrote,

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/esmtp username@gmail.com <<EOF
Subject: "$TR_TORRENT_NAME" finished.
This is an automatic message from your friendly transmission-daemon
($TR_APP_VERSION), your files are in $TR_TORRENT_DIR .
Have a nice day!
EOF
```

To be honest, I found this online. So I installed esmtp. I configured it and made sure the script send email and it works! However I do not get an email when a torrent is completed.

Things I have already done,

- I have also changed the group ownership of /usr/bin/esmtp and the
  script to debian-transmission.
- Made the script executable
- Enabled run script after torrent finishes in the settings.json file. Gave it the exact path
- Checked if running the script manually sends an email.

But this still does not work. Please help.

Comment: Any errors you can provide?

Comment: So what does Transmission's logs say? If esmtp is working and you have the correct paths in settings.json for script-torrent-done-filename and has made sure that script-torrent-done-enabled is set to true, this is probably a permission problem.

Comment: @Joppe Please let me know where I can find the logs for transmission. I did check /var/log/syslog, and noticed that transmission does call the script. But I couldn't anything else out of it.

Comment: I think it logs to the syslog. Just for debugging purposes. What about replacing your script with something a little simpler that just touches a file in the /tmp folder? If that works, you can at least be sure that the script is indeed executed by Transmission.

Comment: Transmission-daemon sometimes have a problem with editing the settings.json file.You need to make sure that its not running before editing the file or changes don't take place.Have you verified that the changes are intact in settings.json?COuld be worth looking at.

Comment: @AwesomeUser I sort of gave up since I couldn't find the solution. I am using my PI for another purpose. Should I delete the question then?